# How to find number of subscribers per question?

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to find the number of subscriber per question. The challenge here is that users are subscribing more then once, but I only need to count when that user subscribe the first time. I am still learning please if someone can direct me. I have attached a link the table and code I have used

[image: query results]

```
select * , COUNT(GroupQuestionSubscriberId) NumberOfSubscriber
from [dbo].[ADF_GroupQuestionSubscribers]
where GroupQuestionId = 4654
GROUP BY [GroupQuestionSubscriberId], [GroupQuestionId], [UserID], [Status], [CreatedDt]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Example data in a text format is preferred over images (for copy-pasting purposes). Also, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65890768/edit) your question to include the expected result.

Comment: Would it suffice to count `distinct` users subscribing to each question? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

The column `CreatedDt` is very likely to contain unique values for every row of data. Including that column in your `group by` clause will produce many counts that equal `1`. In order for your current query to produce a count of `2` you need two rows with exactly the same `GroupQuestionSubscriberId`, `GroupQuestionId`, `UserID`, `Status` and `CreatedDt`. If all this is not many a lot of sense, then I suggest you brush up on your `group by` knowledge by reading [the documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql).

If the intention is to display that count *next to the available data*, then using a `cross apply` is a possible solution.

**Sample data**

```
create table ADF_GroupQuestionSubscribers
(
  GroupQuestionSubscriberId int,
  GroupQuestionId int,
  UserId int,
  Status nvarchar(10),
  CreatedDt datetime
);

insert into ADF_GroupQuestionSubscribers (GroupQuestionSubscriberId, GroupQuestionId, UserId, Status, CreatedDt) values
(8031, 4654, 32338, 'Subscribed', '2021-01-19 15:41:25.970'),
(8035, 4654, 32299, 'Subscribed', '2021-01-19 15:55:14.123'),
(8038, 4654, 32338, 'Subscribed', '2021-01-19 16:00:27.343'),
(8094, 4654, 32466, 'Subscribed', '2021-01-20 06:42:50.323');
```

**Solution**

```
select gqs.*,
       c.NumberOfSubscribers
from ADF_GroupQuestionSubscribers gqs
cross apply ( select count(distinct gqsc.UserId) as NumberOfSubscribers
              from ADF_GroupQuestionSubscribers gqsc
              where gqsc.GroupQuestionId = gqs.GroupQuestionId ) c
where gqs.GroupQuestionId = 4654;
```

**Result**

```
GroupQuestionSubscriberId  GroupQuestionId  UserId  Status      CreatedDt                NumberOfSubscribers
-------------------------  ---------------  ------  ----------  -----------------------  -------------------
8031                       4654             32338   Subscribed  2021-01-19 15:41:25.970  3
8035                       4654             32299   Subscribed  2021-01-19 15:55:14.123  3
8038                       4654             32338   Subscribed  2021-01-19 16:00:27.343  3
8094                       4654             32466   Subscribed  2021-01-20 06:42:50.323  3
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a74a50facd745a02305eaacc8a5f638) to see things in action.

Edit: solution updated with new expected result information.

Comment: Yes sorry i want the result in the same table

Comment: This information does not belong in a comment, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65890768/edit) and improve your question by adding the expected result. Solution and linked fiddle above have been updated.